How to write a getter which accesses a heap-allocated member variable
Lets say I have the member:
char* name;

When writing a getter function to this member, is this the correct way:
char* getName(){
    return name;
}

But when we do this, now user of this class can change name without a setter since the user has the pointer to the heap variable.
I thought of this solution:
char* getName(){
    char* otherName;
    otherName = new char[10];
    strcpy(otherName, name);
    return otherName;
}

But now, since the function creates a heap variable, the user can forget to delete the heap variable and it will be garbage. That's why this implementation does not feel the correct way to implement the getter function for this member too.
How should I implement it?

How should I implement it? -- Since you are using C++, use std::string, not char *.

Ownership. Keep a std::string and only give away a const char*

const char * const

@PaulMcKenzie writing this getter for an assignment given by university and we are limited to char* since they want us to learn constructors, destructors etc.

writing this getter for an assignment given by university and we are limited to char* since they want us to learn constructors, destructors etc. -- Your university is ripping you off.  You can learn what constructors and destructors are without using char * .  The std::string class has been officially part of C++ for 26 years now, probably older than most of the people in your class.  -- otherName = new char[10];-- Who is responsible for calling delete[] on this memory you allocated?  The whole point of learning C++ is to not have to deal with these issues, unlike writing C code.

❶ Whenever I provide a accessor that allows modification access — it is because that is the behavior I desire. Just because it is named “getX” does not mean it is not meant to allow setting/modifying X.  ❷ You were given this design to work with. Don’t waste your time trying to “fix” it. Assume that the designer either knew what he was doing or was just didn’t know better and therefore it doesn’t matter anyway.

(SO comment text fields do not respect non-breaking space characters.)

As mentioned in the comments, you really should use std::string; anything else is just bad (very bad) C++. But if you're constrained to using char*, what's wrong with
char const* getName() const { return name; }

Just return a pointer which doesn't allow modification.
Note that this still can be a source of lifetime issues -- anything which calls the destructor of the object, or causes the object to delete the pointed to memory, will invalidate the returned pointer. This is perhaps an even stronger argument for using std::string.
Whatever you do, do not return a newly allocated copy of the string, expecting the client to delete it. The client won't, and you'll leak memory.

As noted in comments, use std::string rather than char arrays. E.g.
class Person {
    std::string name;

public:
    Person(std::string name) : name(name) { }

    // When called on a const Person object,
    // we return a copy of the name.
    std::string get_name() const { return name; }

    // When called on a non-const Person object,
    // we return a reference, allowing name to be changed.
    std::string& get_name() { return name; }
};

If you are constrained to using char arrays, you can still use this.
class Person {
    char *name;

public:
    Person(char *n) : name(new char[strlen(n)+1]) { 
        strcpy(name, n);
    }

    // When called on a const Person object,
    // we return a copy of the name.
    char *get_name() const { 
        char *n = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(n, name);
        return n;
    }

    // When called on a non-const Person object,
    // we return a reference, allowing name to be changed.
    const char*& get_name() { return name; }
};

But now you have to define constructors as well as handle copy and move semantics following the rule of three/five/zero.
class Person {
    char *name;

public:
    Person(char *n) : name(new char[strlen(n) + 1]) { 
        strcpy(name, n);
    }

    ~Person() { delete[] name; }

    Person(const Person& other) 
    : name(new char[strlen(other.name) + 1])
    {
        strcpy(name, other.name);
    }

    Person& operator=(const Person& other) {
        if (&other == this) return *this;

        delete[] name;
        name = new char[strlen(other.name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, other.name);

        return *this;
    }

    Person(Person&& other) : name(other.name) {
        other.name = nullptr;
    }

    Person& operator=(Person&& other) {
        name = other.name;
        other.name = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    char *get_name() const { 
        char *n = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(n, name);
        return n;
    }

    const char*& get_name() { return name; }
};

Do as you please, but I'm picking the std::string based solution.

Your operator=s leak the existing buffer, I believe.

So does the get_name function, if the client doesn't delete the results (and it's almost sure that some clients will forget). Not to mention his proposal for a non-const get_name, which will allow things like setting the pointer in the object to point to a string literal or a local char[], causing no end of problems in the destructor.
